# How to disable caching in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire

When I send a GET request twice with Alamofire I get the same response but I'm expecting a different one. I was wondering if it was because of the cache, and if so I'd like to know how to disable it.

Comment: For me none of the solutions below, or any that i found worked. Turned out, my hosting provider went through some changes and the JSON file was 'stuck' even though i would edit it, it always kept presenting the same file. Used another host and it worked. Probably few will have the same issue but it's worth noting.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

swift 3, alamofire 4

My solution was:

creating extension for Alamofire:

```
extension Alamofire.SessionManager{
    @discardableResult
    open func requestWithoutCache(
        _ url: URLConvertible,
        method: HTTPMethod = .get,
        parameters: Parameters? = nil,
        encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
        headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)// also you can add URLRequest.CachePolicy here as parameter
        -> DataRequest
    {
        do {
            var urlRequest = try URLRequest(url: url, method: method, headers: headers)
            urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData // <<== Cache disabled
            let encodedURLRequest = try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
            return request(encodedURLRequest)
        } catch {
            // TODO: find a better way to handle error
            print(error)
            return request(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com/wrong_request")!))
        }
    }
}
```

and using it:

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default
            .requestWithoutCache("https://google.com/").response { response in
                print("Request: \(response.request)")
                print("Response: \(response.response)")
                print("Error: \(response.error)")
        }
```

Comment: Agree! Thank you. I've made a requestWithCache function too and now I simply use the proper one. I think this should be included in Alamofire by default

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Are you sure this prevents reading from cache and not just prevents writing to cache? So if there is still something in cache you'll get that anyway? I'm experiencing caching problems with the iTunes lookup that I use to check if there is a new app version: [https://itunes.apple.com/nl/lookup/?id=1234567890](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/lookup/?id=1234567890). Clearing the cache with removeAllCachedResponses() does work though.

Comment: Can you please help me how to enable cache up to 3 Minutes using Alamofire?

Comment: Cache lifetime can be set on server side in Cache-Control: max-age=. To find out, how to do same thing using Alamofire, create another question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 53):

You have a few options.

#### Disabling the URLCache Completely

```
let manager: Manager = {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.URLCache = nil
    return Manager(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

#### Configuring the Request Cache Policy

```
let manager: Manager = {
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    return Manager(configuration: configuration)
}()
```

Both approaches should do the trick for you. For more information, I'd suggest reading through the documentation for [NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/) and [NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLCache). Another great reference is NSHipster article on [NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/).

Comment: Where should this code go?  In app delegate?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @user3246173 see [Alamofire#manager](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manager)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. And also after reading all content in the attached links I still don't know where to call this code.

Comment: At some point "Manager" became "SessionManager" and some other things changed. Swift 3 version: `let manager: SessionManager = {
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
            return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        }()`

Answer (score 49):

This is what worked for me.

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

**Swift 3**

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. Calling the above code every time just before I make a network call.

Comment: @Andrej instead of that I just called it in the AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`

Answer (score 8):

```
func getImage(url: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: urlRequest)
    //URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()

    Alamofire.request(url).responseData { (dataResponse) in
        guard let data = dataResponse.data else {
            return completion(nil)
        }
        completion(UIImage(data: data, scale:1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Alamofire 4** and **Swift 3**:

```
// outside function, inside class
var sessionManager: SessionManager!

func someFunc() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.urlCache = nil
    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    sessionManager.request("http://example.com/get").responseJSON { response in
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: For the comment above: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/157

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32230328/5790492 Better update answer than duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> [This approach doesn't disable caching, it merely makes sure that
>   cached files aren't reused]

An easier way to get past cache problem for a particular call is to just add a random number in the call params.

For Swift 3, you can use, `arc4random()` to generate a random number.

Comment: Yes, not a good approach to stop call caching, but a quick way to avoid cached data for a particular call. Useful for testing, obviously not a solution to get rid of caching as each of the call with a random number would still get cached.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by doing

```
configuration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add cache-control to your headers.

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)",
               "Cache-Control": "no-cache"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically **removing a cached response** before firing that request again would be more appropriate like:

```
let url = "http://google.com"
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: urlRequest)

Alamofire
  .request(urlRequest)
  .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
    //handle response
}
```

Comment: How is your case is like?

Comment: `urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData` worked