# Alamofire how to detect image have been updated on the server?

Tags: caching, swift2, alamofire

I used alamofire to download and display images. And the cache is working great but when i updated the image of the same url link it doesn't reflect the update on my app. How can i tackle this problem? This is an brief code i used for displaying image.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://myserver.com/image/12345.png")

Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseData({ response in

if let imageData = UIImage(data: response.result.value!) {
    self.testImageView.image = imageData
}
})
```

Comment: Try disable caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199494/alamofire-how-remove-cache

Comment: definitely need caching but would like to know how to remove specific cached response if there are updates on the images with the same url.