# Calling api giving same response even response data is changed

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am new to iOS and want to call an API for login. I am using `Alamofire` for HTTP request. I am getting a response from the server but I guess it is saving response in cache. So if I call api with different data is printing same response again. And one more question is I want to save session for later api call. How can I save session data and use it in header for later api call?

**This is my Login API Call**

```
let params = ["identity": txtId.text!, "pass": txtPassword.text!]

AF.request(LOGIN_URL, method: .post, parameters: params as Parameters).responseJSON { response in

    print("response = \(response.result.value)")

}
```

Comment: It can be backend issue..please verify

Comment: No its not. I already developed android app and there is no issue. @SaurabhJain

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to remove caches is to call this code before your network call:

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Or you can also remove caches for a single request:

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://...")!)
URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: urlRequest)
```

Then, make your network call:

```
let params = ["identity": txtId.text!, "pass": txtPassword.text!]

AF.request(LOGIN_URL, method: .post, parameters: params as Parameters).responseJSON { response in
    print("response = \(response.result.value)")
}
```

Comment: I added `URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()` before params but its not working

Comment: @AjayGohel What about the second option?

Comment: for second option how can i attach params to it?

Comment: @AjayGohel I've found this issue that could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199494/how-to-disable-caching-in-alamofire