# Swift 4 - Alamofire - Authenticate NTLM works with invalid credentials

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am having an issue with authenticate NTLM credenitals, when I use valid credentials, it works, but when I use invalid credentials it does not fail, it works as the same as it would with valid credentials. This is only the case when I enter valid credentials first. Is there away to clear the credentials or what am I doing wrong here? Here is my code:

```
func loginUser(_ username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)
    {

        let user = username

        let password = password

        let url = webservice

        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .none)

        let headers = ["Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
                (response) in

                print(response.result)

                switch response.result {

                case .success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {

                        completion(true)

                    }else{

                        print("There is error in the server response")

                        completion(false)
                    }

                case .failure (let error):

                    print("The NTLM request error is: ", error.localizedDescription)

                    completion(false)

                }

            }

    }
```

One thing I did notice, if I enter valid creds, then wait a few minutes and enter invalid ones it works as expected.

UPDATE

I have updated my code like so:

```
func loginUser(_ username: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Bool) -> Void)
    {

        let user = username

        let password = password

        let url = webservice

        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .none)

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

        urlRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        urlRequest.httpMethod = "get"

        urlRequest.setValue("application/json;odata=verbose", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")

        urlRequest.setValue("application/json;odata=verbose", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        Alamofire.request(urlRequest).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
                (response) in

                switch response.result {

                case .success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {


                       completion(true)

                    }else{

                        print("There is error in the server response")

                        completion(false)
                    }

                case .failure (let error):

                    print("The NTLM request error is: ", error.localizedDescription)

                    completion(false)

                }

            }

    }
```

To add a cache policy, but I still get the same result :(

Comment: Based on your last sentence, you are probably hitting a cache

Answer (score 0):

`.failure` is not returned for HTTP errors.  You need to look at the response code in the .success case for the HTTP response that indicates that auth failed.

Look here: [Swift Alamofire: How to get the HTTP response status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131253/swift-alamofire-how-to-get-the-http-response-status-code) for how to do that.

Or you might be hitting a cache. See: [How to disable caching in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199494/how-to-disable-caching-in-alamofire)

Comment: yea the response code is the same with valid vs invalid credentials....200

Comment: If you are 100% positive you sent the wrong creds, there appears to be a bug in the server.

Comment: I think it might be a caching issue, just gotta figure out how to clear the cache

Comment: Instead of clearing it, make your request not use caching. `urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData`

Comment: I applied a cachePolicy, but it did not work, see updated question

Comment: Use CharlesProxy or Wireshark to see exactly what is being sent. Charles has a free trial: https://www.charlesproxy.com (Wireshark is open source but Charles is way easier)